# ElasticSearch PutMapping API: MapperParsingException Root type mapping not empty after parsing

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I have a River on my local instance of ES 1.3.4 and JDBC For MySql 1.3.4.4

This river is working fine and importing data in ES. Problem I am facing that one of my field is a text field and has spaces in it. For example 'Real Time Calculator'. ES is indexing it as 'real', 'time' and 'calculator' instead of 'Real Time Calculator'.

So I am creating mapping using below mentioned JSON:

```
{
    "sale_test": {
        "properties": {
            "Client": {
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "OfferRGU": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "SaleDate": {
                "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                "type": "date"
            },
            "State": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Command:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/my_type
```

But I am getting below mentioned error:

```
> {"error":"MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after
> parsing! Remaining fields:   [sale_test :
> {properties={Client={type=string, index=not_analyzed},
> OfferRGU={type=long}, SaleDate={type=date, format=dateOptionalTime},
> State={type=string}}}]]","status":400}
```

When I try to view current mapping using below mentioned command:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/dgses/sale_test_river/_mapping
```

I get only this: **{}**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your type is not consistent, in the API call the type is **my_type**

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/my_type
```

then it becomes **sale_test** in the JSON message.

Having a consistent type will fix your problem:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/sale_test -d '
    { 
     "sale_test": { 
       "properties": { 
         "Client": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }, 
         "OfferRGU": { "type": "long" }, 
         "SaleDate": { "type": "date", "format": "dateOptionalTime" },
         "State": { "type": "string" }
         } 
       } 
    }'
```

---

Here you have both a *new index* and a *new type*:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/dgses/sale_test_river/_mapping
```

Correcting the index and type gives me:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/sale_test/_mapping?pretty
{
  "myindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "sale_test" : {
        "properties" : {
          "Client" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "OfferRGU" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "SaleDate" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "State" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was typing issue. I got the mapping and after reading Elastic Search documentation I realized that we can not update mapping for an already created index. We need to delete the previous mapping first and then create new mapping for this index. If there is any other way around please share. Thanks.